# use rspec factory Exception: undefined method delete for nil:NilClass

Tags: rspec, factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
     name "test"
   end
end
```

use factory(:product)

(rdb:1) p Factory(:product)

NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

Help me thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more info, like the full backtrace and the code of the Product class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same error message as you did. I don't know about the code inside your product model but I got this exact error message and google sent me here.

The source of this error for me was that I defined an initialize method without calling the parent's intialize. A better idea than overriding the initialize method in ActiveRecord objects is to use the after_initialize callback

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize do 
    # own init stuff goes here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The factory definition is so simple that it's very likely your concern is not the factory definition.  I would verify that it's possible to manually create a Product from the console.

For instance, I've seen this error when I've had errors related to an initializer.